# Excessive Internal memory consumed while using two different asyncTask on same RealmObject Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, realm

**1..  If i run two methods** `create2YearsDatabse();` **at one anpplication run session
     then kill the program completely and then in the next run run the method :**

```
updateAutoGeneratedCalendar();
```

**then the result is as expected it takes about 
     2-3 MB of memory**

**2. But if i run** `create2YearsDatabse()` and `onSuccess()` `callback` of `async Task` it is using  then the memory it takes in **internal memory suddenly goes to more than 400 MB.**

```
// The methods are managed in this way:

public void create2YearsDatabase() {
        new BGAsyncTasks(context, new ThreadCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                final SettingAndStatusDTO settingDto = realm.where(SettingAndStatusDTO.class).findFirst();
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        //because two years has more or equal to 730 days
                        if (realm.where(CalendarDto.class).findAll().size() >= 730) {
                            settingDto.setIs2YearsFullDBCreated(true);
                            context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.shared_pref_name),Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(SplashActivity.FIRST_TIME_RUN,false).apply();
                        }
                    }
                });
                SplashActivity.freshRun = false;
                startDashBoard();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
            }
        }, BGAsyncTasks.CREATE_INITIALIZE_2_YEARS_CALENDAR).execute();
    }

    public void updateAutoGeneratedCalendar() {
        new BGAsyncTasks(context, new ThreadCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.i("datatest", "full data size" + realm.where(CalendarDto.class).findAll().size());
                final SettingAndStatusDTO settingDto = realm.where(SettingAndStatusDTO.class).findFirst();
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        if (realm.where(CalendarDto.class).findAll().size() >= 32000)
                            settingDto.setIs90YearsDBCreated(true);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
            }
        }, BGAsyncTasks.CREATE_AUTO_GENERATE_CALENDAR).execute();
    }
```

**And My Async Task Looks like this :**

```
public class BGAsyncTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // Intention variables
    public static final int CREATE_INITIALIZE_2_YEARS_CALENDAR = 0;
    public static final int CREATE_AUTO_GENERATE_CALENDAR = 1;

    // Message from the Activity/Fragment.
    ThreadCallBack callBack;
    Context context;
    int intention;
    IParseData parser ;

    //Constructor for bg processes.
    public BGAsyncTasks(Context c, ThreadCallBack callBack, int DATA_TYPE_FROM_RES) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
        this.context = c;
        this.intention = DATA_TYPE_FROM_RES;
        this.parser  = new ParseData(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        switch (intention) {
            case CREATE_AUTO_GENERATE_CALENDAR: {
                final Realm asyncRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                for (int i = 2000; i <= 2090; i++) {
                    if (i < 2072 || i > 2073) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                            parser.setOnemonthData(i, j);
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i("datatest", "year:" + i);
                }
            }
            case CREATE_INITIALIZE_2_YEARS_CALENDAR: {
                String thisMonthString;
                for (int i = 2072; i <=2073; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                        thisMonthString = getStringByMonth(i, j);// returns the json string
                        parser.parseOneMonthData(fixFormatting(thisMonthString));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        callBack.onSuccess();
    }
}
```

**And  my Parse and saving to Database methods look like this:**

```
public class ParseData implements IParseData {
Context context;
Realm realm;
CalendarDto mCalendarDto;
public ParseData(Context c) {
        context = c;
        mCalendarDto = new CalendarDto();
    }


public void parseOneMonthData(String monthData) {
        //parse json data of one month and return as DTO of size equal
        //to no of days in that month

        try {
            JSONArray oneMonthJsonData = new JSONArray(monthData);
            int length = oneMonthJsonData.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                saveOneDayData(oneMonthJsonData.optJSONObject(i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public void saveOneDayData(final JSONObject singleTouple) {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();       
        // parsing the data of one day so that it can be used everywhere.
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                   mCalendarDto.setDayInfo(singleTouple.optString(DataItems.DAY_INFO));
                    mCalendarDto.setMahina(singleTouple.optString(DataItems.MAHINA));
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mCalendarDto);    
            }
        });    
    }

// saving data by month and year

public void  setOnemonthData(final int yr, final int mnt) {    
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        mCalendarDto.setMonthEnId(currentEngMonth);
                        mCalendarDto.setMonthNpId(month);
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mCalendarDto);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Here is my   Calendar Realm Object :**

```
public class CalendarDto extends RealmObject  {
    public CalendarDto() {
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    private int primaryDayId
    private String sakey;
    private String raja;
    private String mantri;
    private String nepalSambat;

// more variables and ...........

////  autogenerated getters and settetrs      
////////

}
```

Comment: How is the Realm managed in the async task? I doesn't look like you open and close it there? A high memory consumption might occur if you don't close Realms again, but your case seems very extreme especially if you only have 2 threads open. How are you measuring the memory usage?

Comment: i get a realmInstance (default )  and i do realm.executeTransaction(new Trans......);

Comment: Can you please update the code in the first post then? Because right now it impossible to see that.

Comment: sir i think this problem is with two different realm object created by two different threads

Comment: if there is only one thread that is dealing with realm DB i get the perfect result but once an app is opened and  during the full lifetime (even counting when it gets minimized by pressing the home button)  there exist two realm instances which tries to write database then i get such problem

Comment: Most likely you are not closing the Realm instance again, which means you keep opening Realm instances on the background thread. Please read: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances

Comment: shall i close the realm in every index of the loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114088/discussion-between-laxman-bhattarai-and-christian-melchior).

Comment: Keeping transactions open for longer periods can easily cause problems. Please take a look at https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#large-realm-file-size

Comment: There is two problems with your code: 1) You are not closing the Realm at the end of doInBackground() and 2) You are executing transactions inside a loop. For each transaction you are creating a new version that other threads have to keep a diff to, which is why you see the explosion in file/memory.

Comment: So what is the best way to do so ? passing the realm instance to the loop ?

Comment: But what i am surprised is that works fine even if inside loop if i run in different app sessions ..

Comment: Maybe you can find some inspiration in our example: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/threadExample

Comment: @ChristianMelchior he creates a new transaction for every single day on background threads that have Realm instances that are never closed. He'll have many many many versions.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  if i close the instance then i get "realm instance closed no longer usable or sth like that "

Comment: @geisshirt  with reference to file  https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/threadExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/threads/AsyncTaskFragment.java   ,  here the author has executed one async task , which is working exactly fine for me , what is not working for me is that there are two async task i want to run but one after another and i want to have a way of knowing if the first async task is completed. In my case if i close the realm after first completes and try to execute another async task just after it , then the realm object is not usable anymore coz its closed.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior out of curiousity, does every `commitTransaction()` increment the version of the Realm? so if he executes like 200 transactions on a non-auto-updating background thread, does it create 200 versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    switch (intention) {
        case CREATE_AUTO_GENERATE_CALENDAR: {
            final Realm asyncRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // <--- this line
```

and

```
public void saveOneDayData(final JSONObject singleTouple) {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();  // <--- this line
```

and

```
public void  setOnemonthData(final int yr, final int mnt) {    
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // <--- this line
```

On background threads, you should close the Realm instance after using them in a `finally` block.

In this case, you are opening a new Realm instance for every single day twice, and you're not closing any of them.

On a background thread, best practice is to open only **one Realm instance**, and then **close it after the execution is complete.**

```
Realm realm = null;

try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    //do things
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
         realm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what i am confused most is about where to declare the realm , if i do that in async task and pass  it to saveday() or save Month() then  close realm instance at the end of do in background , i get the error that the realm object is already closed and no longer usable or sth like that when i try to run the updateAutogeneratedCalendar().

Comment: You can take reference to this file  https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/threadExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/threads/AsyncTaskFragment.java   ,  here the author has executed one async task , which is working exactly fine for me , what is not working for me is that there are two async task i want to run but one after another and i want to have a way of knowing if the first async task is completed. In my case if i close the realm after first completes and try to execute another async task just after it , then the realm object is not usable anymore coz its closed.

Comment: Open a Realm instance in the beginning of doInBackground()  method, and close it in finally at the end of doInBackground().

Comment: and where to call the next async task from ?  from  postexecute()?  if i close it there how can i use realm for another asyncTask? are their any other methods than getdefaultInstance() that i can used to get the realm instance, although another realm instance was closed earlier ?

Comment: The async task should open its realm in doInBackground at the start, and close it at the end of doInBackground. But if you need to run realm related code in onPostExecute, then that should also either use the dedicated UI thread realm, or open its own instance and close it at the beginning and end.

Comment: You shouldn't reuse Realm instances between async tasks, which also means you shouldn't use RealmObjects across async tasks. Instead can either just send the primary key and query for the object again or create an in-memory copy using `copyFromRealm`

Comment: No luck again , it works fine to write to the database but the memory usage is still high ... i think this is an issue...

Comment: No, if the memory usage is high, then you're still not closing your realm instances right.

Comment: And you should also keep your number of transactions on non-looper (not UI) threads to the minimum. Or you could create your own Looper thread to keep your Realm instances up to date.

Comment: Sorry  @EpicPandaForce i didn't get your answer fully at first and during the impelementation i mistook by forgetting to remove realm= Realm.getDefaultInstance(); now with few other tweaks i am able to fix the issue